# how to resolve nginx 502 bad-gateway error

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I've containerized the next.js web application and hosted in aws ec-2. using nginx as proxy server

this is the only working page

> /

not working for any other pages (paths),it throws **502 bad-gate-way**

*EX:*

> /etc

> /slug/page

this is the nginx cofiguration

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;


location  / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:300;
}
```

}

how can I Forward all paths to a specific port?

Comment: `502 Bad Gateway` means that you have problem with your backend, not nginx itself. Please, show us your full nginx config, you can do it executing `nginx -T`

Comment: this my basic configuration of nginx, and I didn't add any other configs

Comment: @ShaheelAhzar ok, what listens `300` port on your `localhost`, what kind of backend?

Comment: It was a Dockerized next.js project

Comment: @ShahellAzhar can you access its host and port besides nginx? I mean just regular access. Any errors in docker instance logs?

Comment: docker instance working fine and the only path working is /, other paths are not working, it throws 502 Bad Gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # reverse proxy for next server
                proxy_pass http://localhost:300;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            # we need to remove this 404 handling
                # because next's _next folder and own handling
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        } 

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all
        }
}
```

I've add this nginx configuration, now it's working fine.